# what is the size and length of text(10) in sql? and also what does length 10 specifies? and can we able to give length like 10 to text in sql?

Tags: mysql

what is the size of of column text(10) in bytes in mysql?
what is the maximum value stored in this column?

```
QString query = "CREATE TABLE VOUCHER_DETAILS("
                     "V_NO,"
                     "NAME text(10),"
                     "PAYMENT_MODE,"
                     "NOTE,"
                     "PHONE,"
                     "PRODUCT,"
                   );";
    qry.prepare(query);
    qry.exec();
```

Comment: Depends on column's charset. 10, 20, 30 or 40 bytes for value, 1 byte for data length, 1 byte for NULL mark. Really, the column will be created as TINYTEXT.

Comment: 'An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done, MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to hold values M characters long.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html

Comment: @P.Salmon We may specify the length instead of precise datatype specifying - this will be parsed successfully and won't cause an error.

Comment: @Akina true and will generate tinytext datatype (in this case)

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, the data length specification will be lost. If needed it can be restricted with CHECK (do not allow to insert more) or with trigger (cut off excess symbols).